# parse \r strings from CSV file

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, csv, split

I am reading a csv file in javascript by first spliting by newline then spiliting by comma.
I am able to parse the whole of csv successfully but only one thing is left. i.e.
the last one

I don't know how to remove those \r . The code I am using is

```
    function csvJSON(csv){
        var lines=csv.split("\n");
        var result = [];
        var headers=lines[0].split(",");
        for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){
            var obj = {};
            var currentline=lines[i].split(",");
            for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
                  obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
            }
            result.push(obj);
         }
         return result; //JavaScript object
     }
```

Comment: var lines=csv.split(/\r?\n/); try this

Answer (score 8):

By [standard](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) CSV lines are ended with CRLF ('\r\n'). But if you expect to support non-stardard line endings also test for others as well:

```
var lines=csv.split(/\r\n|\n|\r/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `trim()` to remove `\r`

```
obj[headers[j].trim()] = currentline[j].trim();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below code

```
var data='{"batting_score":"52","wickets":"0","runs_conceded":"12","catches":"0","stumps":"0","opposition":"v Pakistan","ground":"Dhaka","date":"18-Mar-12","match_result":"won","result_margin":"6 wickets","toss":"lost","batting_innings":"2nd"}'.replace(/\r/g,'');
var JsonData=JSON.parse(data);
```

now you can access properties like below

```
JsonData.batting_score //52
```